# Hide section when there's no messages to display

Tags: javascript, html

I need to hide the div when there are no messages to display, Javascript is used to display the messages. I have tried solutions to similar questions with no success.

HTML:

```
 <div class="msgList">
    <section id="messages">
        <h2>Messages</h2>
        <ul id="users-messages">

        </ul>
    </section>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
// Display messages in list
const messageSection = document.getElementById('messages');
const messageList = messageSection.children[1];
const newMessage = document.createElement('li');
newMessage.classList.add('msg-List');
newMessage.innerHTML = `<a href="mailto:${user_email.value}">${user_name.value}</a>. 
<span id="msg-span"> wrote: ${user_message.value}</span>`;
```

Comment: the way this code is written currently doesn't show the expected output—maybe edit the question to include a fiddle with a working version?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, let me add the whole block of code

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional for `user_message.value`. You add the style of display none to your message section if `user_message.value` is null or empty.

Otherway is you can set the innerHTML as an empty string if there is no message.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It didn't work, I am going to edit and post the whole set of codes

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with CSS, you could use the `:empty` sudo-class:

```
#users-messages:empty{
  display: none;
}
```